# How to replace a string item in local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I can update my todo list in UI and it's replacing prev value to new value.

```
const { prev, newValue} = action.payload;

return Object.assign({}, state, { toDoList: state.toDoList.map(i => i !== prev ? i : newValue)});
```

However, I can't do the same thing in localStorage.

```
const storageItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));
    
storageItems.map(i => i !== prev ? i : newValue);
    
localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(storageItems));
```

storageItems array is not updating I don't know why.

Is updating local storage different ? How can we update the storage?

Comment: `.map()` returns a new array, does not update the existing one.

Comment: To add to the previous comment. Save the result of the map in a variable and pass that to the `JSON.stringify`

Comment: you should modify as storageItems= storageItems.map(i => i !== prev ? i : newValue);

Comment: @whitefang yes, although `storageItems` would need to be a `let`

Comment: You can directly map the items you get from the local storage because as @VLAZ mentioned "`.map()` returns a new array" `const storageItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")).map(i => i !== prev ? i : newValue);`